# passing values from one sub routine to another in perl

Tags: perl

Need some assistance constructing my perl code. I have parts of it working where I am able to extract results from one call to a subroutine `$cmd->ls("$chkdir");` and get the result from the key `$dirnm->{path}` (eg. Directory: '/home/mydir').

What I need to do is pass that result ('/home/dir') to another subroutine as input to a dbi connection with a sql statement (`sub results_in`)

So how do I construct this, so that I can pass values called from one sub routine to another?

**Example Code:**

```
my $DirResults = $cmd->ls("$chkdir"); #$chkdir is directory passed as argument
for my $dirnm ( @{$DirResults->{directory}} ) {
    print "Directory:  " . $dirnm->{path} . "\n";
}

#
### Database handle
#
my $dbh_oracle = DBI->connect(
      $CFG{oracle_dbi_connect},
      $CFG{db_user},
      $CFG{db_cred},
      {AutoCommit => 0,
       RaiseError => 0,
       PrintError => 0}) or die ("Cannot connect to the database: ".$DBI::errstr."\n");
my $res_in=results_in($dirnm->{path});  #Here for pseudo code
$dbh_oracle->disconnect();       

sub results_in
{
  my $sth= $dbh_oracle->prepare(q{
       INSERT into mydirs
          VALUES (280, '$res_in')}) ||
      die ("Cannot connect to the database: ".$DBI::errstr."\n");
  $sth->execute;
  $sth->finish;
}
```

Comment: Your call is correct. The problem is that `$dirnm` only exists in the loop. It's pretty obvious what you want to do when the loop is only entered once, but what do you want to do when the loop is never entered, and what do you want to do when the loop is entered more than once?

Comment: i'd like to insert a `$dirnm` for everyone found if I that's possible. if there's 0 result from `$dirnm`, then exit all together. I basically want to input any results i find into this table.

Answer (score 6):

Your call is correct. The problem is that`$dirnm` only exists in the loop, but you use it outside of the loop. You need to move the loop between the point where the connection is opened and the point where it is closed.

At the same time, let's do a little cleaning. You don't want to `prepare` more than once; it's wasteful. One avoids doing that by using placeholders.

Placeholders also saves you from having to convert from path into a SQL literal, which you poorly attempted to do by adding quotes around. That's a recipe for an injection bug/attack.

So we end up with the following:

```
my $dbh_oracle = DBI->connect(...);

my $sth = $dbh_oracle->prepare(q{
   INSERT INTO mydirs VALUES (280, ?, DEFAULT, 1700)
});

my $DirResults = $cmd->ls($chkdir);
for my $dirnm (@{ $DirResults->{directory} }) {
    $sth->execute( $dirnm->{path} );
}

$sth->finish();
$dbh_oracle->disconnect();
```

(Error handling removed to keep things short and to the point for this post. Do keep it or use `RaiseError=>1`.)

There was really no point in having a sub (other than `execute`) anymore, so I didn't use one. But since you specifically asked about sub calling, the following illustrates what the code could look like with a sub call:

```
sub results_in {
   my ($sth, $path) = @_;
   $sth->execute($path);
}

...
my $DirResults = $cmd->ls($chkdir);
for my $dirnm ( @{$DirResults->{directory}} ) {
    results_in($sth, $dirnm->{path});
}
...
```

Comment: thanks for looking at this. I will go without call another sub routine, but I appreciate you adding the illustration for reference as well.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just forgetting to receive the parameter using `@_` to `results_in()`?  E.g.:

```
sub results_in
{
  my ($dir) = @_;
  my $sth= $dbh_oracle->prepare(qq{
       INSERT into mydirs
          VALUES (280, '$dir', DEFAULT, 1700)}) ||
      die ("Cannot connect to the database: ".$DBI::errstr."\n");
  $sth->execute;
  $sth->finish;
}
```

Did I miss something?

Note that I also changed `q{` to `qq{` so that `$dir` would be interpolated (versus being inserted as the literal string `'$dir'`)

Comment: Consider what happens when the path `ikegami's files` is encountered.